# I want to create multiple resized pngs from one svg file. I want to use Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

[How can I create multiple sizes of a specific image easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073639/how-can-i-create-multiple-sizes-of-a-specific-image-easily)
The linked question was the same as the one I have,
If you do that, the bat file will close immediately and nothing will be done ..
I created an svg file and dragged it to a bat file.
~ My environment ~
I have already installed Imagemagick.
I'm using Windows 10.

I'm not very good at English so I use translation. I'm sorry if you feel bad ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick can write several files from a single command using the "-write" operation. This command will output 8 images with different sizes and different filenames...

```
magick input.png ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 180x180! -write AppIconMask@3x~ipad.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 180x180! -write AppIconMask@3x~iphone.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 152x152! -write AppIconMask@2x~ipad.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 120x120! -write AppIconMask@2x~iphone.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 84x84! -write GameAppIconMask@2x.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 80x80! -write SpotlightAppIconMask@2x.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 58x58! -write TableIconMask@2x.png ) ^
    ( -clone 0 -resize 40x40! -write NotificationAppIconMask@2x.png ) ^
    null:
```

The command ends by writing the original input file to "null:", an IM built-in that means write it to nowhere.

If you have ImageMagick v6 use "convert" instead of "magick".